# DirectX primitive rendering at the wrong position

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, renderer

So I'm recoding my rendering engine, starting with the basics. I'm running is to a very weird issue. I'm simply rendering a triangle, but the position is all wrong.

Here's what I'm getting (can't post image cause I don't have enough rep yet):
[Incorrect Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZYIG.png)

That's obviously not what I'm trying to do.

Here's are my vertices I'm defining, what my vertex structure looks like, and what my FVF looks like:

```
CDirect3DHelper::VERTEX vertices[] =
{
    { 300, -300, 0, 1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255) },
    { 0, 300, 0, 1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0) },
    { -300, -300, 0, 1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0) }
}

struct VERTEX
{
    float x, y, z, rhw;
    DWORD color;
};

static const DWORD FVF = D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE;
```

Anyone have any idea what's wrong? I feel like I'm missing something really stupid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates are outside your screen. The X and Y value of the vertex are in screen space where top left is 0,0 and right bottom is width,height

Comment: Wow, I'm an actual idiot, what a stupid mistake! Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Wait, now I'm getting another issue. When I remove my rhw value from my vertex struct and change the FVF to D3DFVF_XYZ, nothing renders anymore... Any idea?

Comment: The RHW component determines whether the given vertices are already transformed (x y z in screen space). If you remove that component the given vertices are in world space and you need to first set a perspective and view matrix using SetTransform

Comment: Yeah I did that. I'm not new to Direct3D. That's why I'm so confused.

Comment: well make sure you're aiming towards the triangle with the view matrix and not too close to it ;)

Comment: One suggestion: Don't use legacy Direct3D 9 (which is over a decade old at this point). Use Direct3D 11 and take a look at the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) including the [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).